# How to programmatically center vertically a label in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6, osx-yosemite

I have a problem with a label. I'm not really sure how to center vertically this label:

```
let textRect = NSMakeRect(newX, newY , 400, 400)

let textTextContent = NSString(string: "label")
let textStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle.defaultParagraphStyle().mutableCopy() as NSMutableParagraphStyle
textStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignment.CenterTextAlignment
```

Horizontally is easy, but vertically I couldn't find a way to do that.

Comment: Are you using Auto layout?

Comment: Yes. I use auto Layout .

Answer (score 2):

I guess there is no `alignment` sort of properties for that. You can use container view and constrain the label to be centred.

[image]

You can add constraints programmatically:

```
containerView.addConstraints([
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .CenterX, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: labelView, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0),
    NSLayoutConstraint(item: containerView, attribute: .CenterY, relatedBy: .Equal, toItem: labelView, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0)
])
```

Comment: if i  use IB to create the label, is easy to align that text vertically, but my label is created programmatically